# Why is my C program not printing anything out?

Tags: c, low-level-io

my code is supposed to be reading in 2 files given on the command line and then printing them out to STDOUT unless a 3rd argument is given, in which case it should print to that file instead of STDOUT. 
I feel like everything is right but when I run the program nothing is printing out. Anything you can spot as to why not? a new set of eyes is always helpful.

```
int main(int ARGC, char *ARGV[]) {
   char buf1[1024];
   char buf2[1024];
   int n=0; 
   int m=0; 
   int fd=open(ARGV[1],O_RDONLY);
   int fd2=open(ARGV[2],O_RDONLY);
   int fd3=open(ARGV[3],O_WRONLY);

   do {
      int n= read(fd,buf1,sizeof(buf1));
      if(n<0) {
         perror("read error1");
      }
      if(fd3!=0) {
         write(fd3,buf1,n);
      }

      if(fd3==0) {
         write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf1,n);
      }

   } while(n==sizeof(buf1));

   do{
      int m=read(fd2,buf2,sizeof(buf2));
      if(m<0) {
         perror("read error2");
      }
      if(fd3!=0) {
         write(fd3,buf2,m);
      }
      if(fd3==0) {
         write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf2,m);
      }
   } while(m==sizeof(buf2));
}
```

Comment: My eyes hurt from trying to follow your inconsistent indentation.

Comment: Ahhh, that's less painful. Thanks, alk.

Comment: Why do you expect `f3` ever getting set to `0`?

Comment: @alk is right. Should initialize to 0, then set it to the result of `open` only if argc > 3. In your code, it will be -1 if undefined behavior doesn't bite you.

Comment: The fds should better be initialised to -1, as `0` **is** a valid file descriptor, only it is not expected to be returned by any of these `open()`s as coded.

Comment: @alk: True, but I don't think it will be returned by `open()` unless one does something silly first.

Comment: "script"? Are you using a C interpreter? C usually produces "programs" :)

Comment: C does nothing but just being ... ;-) @pmg

Comment: Btw: the code seems to work (if being passed three arguments).

Comment: Check that you have 3 arguments before you use them.  Check that the `open()` calls work before using the file descriptors.

Comment: I got the code to work with 2 arguments but it keeps giving me "permission denied" when I try to cat or vi the output file.

Comment: Check the docs for `open`. the 3rd argument controls the permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never going to write to the screen when you leave off the 3rd argument.

`int fd3=open(ARGV[3],O_WRONLY);` with an empty or garbage `ARGV[3]` will likely set `fd3` to `-1`, which is not `0`.  So you will never write to STDOUT_FILENO, but instead write to an invalid file descriptor.

Comment: Well that makes sense! thank you. And everyone else who replied.

Comment: So the lesson learned is: **Always test the outcome of system calls** (`write()` here).

Comment: I got it to print out to STDOUT but not to the output file when a third argument is given?

Comment: The third file needs to exist already ... @RickGarcia Pass `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY` to the third call to `open()` to have the file created in case it does not exist.

Comment: Its creating the file but denying me permission to cat it